# While read line, awk $line with multiple delimiters

Tags: unix, loops, awk, readline

I am trying a small variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327874/while-read-line-awk-line), except I telling awk that the delimiter of the file to be split based on the 5th field can either be a colon ":" or a tab \t. I do the `awk -F '[:\t]'` part alone, it does indeed print the right $5 field.

However, when I try to incorporate this into the bigger command, it returns the following error:

```
                                                             print > f
awk: cmd. line:9:                                            ^ syntax error
```

This is the code:

```
awk -F '[:\t]' '    # read the list of numbers in Tile_Number_List
    FNR == NR {
        num[$1]
        next
    }

    # process each line of the .BAM file
    # any lines with an "unknown" $5 will be ignored
    $5 in num {
        f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        print > f
    } ' Tile_Number_List.txt little.sam
```

Why won't it work with the -F option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the value of `FS` it's this line as pointed to by the error:

```
f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        print > f
```

You have two statements on one line so either separate them with a `;` or a newline:

```
f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"; print > f
```

Or:

```
f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"
print > f
```

---

As full one liner:

```
awk -F '[:\t]' 'FNR==NR{n[$1];next}$5 in n{print > ("Alignments_"$5".sam")}'
```

Or as a script file i.e `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[:\t]" 
}
# read the list of numbers in Tile_Number_List
FNR == NR {
    num[$1]
    next
}
# process each line of the .BAM file
# any lines with an "unknown" $5 will be ignored
$5 in num {
    f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        
    print > f
}
```

To run in this form `awk -f script.awk Tile_Number_List.txt little.sam`.

**Edit:**

The character `-`  is used to represent input from stdin instead of a file with many *nix tools.

```
command | awk -f script.awk Tile_Number_List.txt -
```

Comment: @CarmenSandoval don't forgot to upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, I just need to wait a few minutes :)

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the little.sam instead of indicating it at the end of the line?

little.sam is the standard output of a previous operation and I would rather not have to store it in disk.

How would you pipe it as input to the script.awk? Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello, everyone, I posted a new question related to this one [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407721/while-read-line-awk-line-and-write-to-variable), about how to incorporate this into an .sh script with variables to pass onto this command. I hope you can help :) Many thanks, Carmen