# While read line, awk $line and write to variable

Tags: unix, variables, awk, split, field

I am trying to split a file into different smaller files depending on the value of the fifth field. A very nice way to do this was [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327874/while-read-line-awk-line) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404666/while-read-line-awk-line-with-multiple-delimiters).

However, I am trying to incorporate this into a .sh script for qsub, without much success.

The problem is that in the section where the file to which output the line is specified,

i.e.,  `f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        print > f`

, I need to pass a variable declared earlier in the script, which specifies the directory where the file should be written. I need to do this with a variable which is built for each task when I send out the array job for multiple files.

So say `$output_path` = `./Sample1`

I need to write something like

```
f = $output_path "/Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        print > f
```

But it does not seem to like having a $variable that is not a $field belonging to awk. I don't even think it likes having two "strings" before and after the $5.

The error I get back is that it takes the first line of the file to be split (`little.sam`) and tries to name `f` like that, followed by /Alignments_" $5 ".sam" (those last three put together correctly). It says, naturally, that it is too big a name.

How can I write this so it works?

Thanks!

```
awk -F '[:\t]' '    # read the list of numbers in Tile_Number_List
    FNR == NR {
        num[$1]
        next
    }

    # process each line of the .BAM file
    # any lines with an "unknown" $5 will be ignored
$5 in num {
    f = "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"        print > f
} ' Tile_Number_List.txt little.sam
```

**UPDATE, AFTER ADDING -V TO AWK AND DECLARING THE VARIABLE OPATH**

```
input=$1
outputBase=${input%.bam}

mkdir -v $outputBase\_TEST

newdir=$outputBase\_TEST

samtools view -h $input | awk 'NR >= 18' | awk -F '[\t:]' -v opath="$newdir" '

FNR == NR {
    num[$1]
    next
}

$5 in num {
    f = newdir"/Alignments_"$5".sam";
    print > f
} ' Tile_Number_List.txt -

mkdir: created directory little_TEST'
awk: cmd. line:10: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `/Alignments_1101.sam' (Permission denied)
```

Comment: try to add `;` after `$5 ".sam"` or put `print >f` in a new line.

Comment: ALWAYS quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and are fully aware of the caveats and consequences of the filename globbing, wildcard expansion, etc. that occurs when non-quoted variables are used. Also, what is `\_` intended to do in `$outputBase\_TEST`? I THINK you're probably trying to write `"${outputBase}/_TEST"` but it's not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the value of the shell variable such as `$output_path` to `awk` you need to use the `-v` option.

```
$ output_path=./Sample1/

$ awk -F '[:\t]' -v opath="$ouput_path" '    
    # read the list of numbers in Tile_Number_List
    FNR == NR {
        num[$1]
        next
    }

    # process each line of the .BAM file
    # any lines with an "unknown" $5 will be ignored
    $5 in num {
        f = opath"Alignments_"$5".sam"
        print > f
    } ' Tile_Number_List.txt little.sam
```

Also you still have the error from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404666/while-read-line-awk-line-with-multiple-delimiters) left in your script

**EDIT:**

The `awk` variable created with `-v` is `obase` but you use `newdir` what you want is:

```
input=$1
outputBase=${input%.bam}
mkdir -v $outputBase\_TEST
newdir=$outputBase\_TEST

samtools view -h "$input" | awk -F '[\t:]' -v opath="$newdir" '
FNR == NR && NR >= 18 {
    num[$1]
    next
}    
$5 in num {
    f = opath"/Alignments_"$5".sam"   # <-- opath is the awk variable not newdir
    print > f
}' Tile_Number_List.txt -
```

You should also move `NR >= 18` into the second `awk` script.

Comment: +1, for you must have forgot how many answers have you posted for "how to use shell var with awk" :)

Comment: @Kent haha it does come up frequently, could be worse like every single `php` question on parsing HTML with regexp.

Comment: Thanks, sudo_O

I still get an error message after appending -v and declaring the variable.

I have appended this new error to my question.

Comment: @kent and sudo_O  :( Those are the drawbacks of being a noob, one's gotta deal with it! :(

Comment: @CarmenSandoval you used `newdir` in your awk script which is shell variable. The `awk` variable you create with `-v`  is `opath`.

Comment: @CarmenSandoval I didn't mean to blame anybody. sometimes a problem is pretty easy to be solved by searching or self-testing. Usually you will be really "learned" it by doing so. (at least for me it is so).  E.g. your last problem (`opath/newdir`). I think if you read sudo_O's original answer carefully, and take a look your codes, you would spot the error by yourself. Also the errMsg is also clear, why awk attempted to write to your root directory? You may learn it and won't forget it, if sudo_O won't give you working code, but telling you **"add sudo before awk"** that is what he called. :)

Comment: @Sudo_O OK, with your last answer, I know I need to go home for today! Sorry about that, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

awk variables are like C variables - just reference them by name to get their value, no need to stick a "$" in front of them like you do with shell variables:

```
awk -F '[:\t]' '    # read the list of numbers in Tile_Number_List
    FNR == NR {
        num[$1]
        next
    }

    # process each line of the .BAM file
    # any lines with an "unknown" $5 will be ignored
$5 in num {
    output_path = "./Sample1/"
    f = output_path "Alignments_" $5 ".sam"
    print > f
} ' Tile_Number_List.txt little.sam
```